# execution of php script

Tags: php, sockets, serversocket

I know that when we execute a PHP script on localhost, the server runs the code and does the required processing and simply outputs the result to the browser. Recently, I was reading about [socket_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) function which creates a connection for server and client to communicate, but I have a doubt regarding it. Below is what I think, please correct me if i am wrong.

When I run my program (which uses socket_create) by typing http://localhost/myprog.php... The prog commands localhost to make a open a socket. This is ok, but what if I want to create socket on some other server? (Below are two options, please tell me which is correct)

1. If I still run the script on **http://localhost** does that mean the
   script will run on localhost and localhost will make a socket on the
   other server? And if I want to give some input to the other server
   the input will pass through localhost.
2. I can't do it as told above, I would have to run my script on other
   server to create a socket on it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP script is like any other program on machine. If you access script which is on localhost, and this script creates socket then script on your local machine connect to the other server, retrieves output, pass it back to script. If you access some remote host, then script is executed on this remote host - that's only difference.
So the answer is 1.

Comment: @lolo....so what is the difference between this php code which requires localhost to run and a c++ code which also creates a socket on remote server....

Comment: There is no difference in terms of programming. You can run PHP script from command line and you can access C++ program from browser via CGI.

Comment: @lolo...plz explain what is meant by accessing c++ prog from browser via cgi(i am a newbie)....and also when i tried to open a socket on localhost by a php script which ran on localhost, there was no output( the page kept on loading)

Comment: You create program which runs on server to have dynamic web site. No difference if you use PHP, C++ or any other language. The difference is on server. But it's not important, we're going offtopic. If you attach some code then we could help you with this no-output problem. Probably you missuse socket - this is a raw stream, you must implement HTTP protocol to talk with other server (I assume you want access other server via HTTP)

Comment: @lolo...i used the first code by users on this page and replaced ip by 127.0.0.1 instead of 10.203.9.67